# set up Hadoop cluster on mixed OS

Tags: hadoop

I have one MBP with 10.7.4 and one laptop with Ubuntu 12.04. Is it possible to set up a hadoop cluster by such mixed environment?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be anything to stop using a heterogeneous environment for a Hadoop cluster. For development environment it should be OK, but for production it's not.

Mixed environments shouldn't be a matter, but it might take some time to debug issues when setting up Hadoop on different environments. If you are really concerned, then use Virtual Machines.

One thing to note is, on a slow machine the tasks might take a lot of time and might influence the overall time to complete the overall job. More granular splits might help in this scenario.